# Remove text qualifier when copying to variable in postman

Tags: postman

I have an issue using a text variable from a response body and inserting into a request without the text qualifiers.

I'm trying this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("basketid", responseBody);
```

This is the response

> "14b5f921-78d9-4ab2-a5a0-828f00fcf63a"

When I look at the `basketid` variable the text qualifiers are still there which mean that when I call

```
{{url}}/api/{{basketid}}
```

I get an error.

Do anyone know of a way to save the variable without text qualifier?

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me:

```
var _token = responseBody.slice(1,-1);
pm.globals.set("token", _token);
```

Comment: Works great for me. The slice avoid to use potentially harmful "eval" function

Comment: Upvote!  My variation:   var mydata = pm.response.text().slice(1,-1);
pm.environment.set("generatedToken", mydata);

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting "14b5f921-78d9-4ab2-a5a0-828f00fcf63a" as it is in global environment as you said, you can use eval:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(responseBody);
var setObj=eval("("+jsonObj+")");
postman.setGlobalVariable("basketid",setObj);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still gets the same result. The response looks like this: "4b56b4b8-63ec-41e1-97ba-6a2bf38264c1"

Comment: I now tried eval but without stringifying the response. That worked beautifully! Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today while trying to store my token and this is what worked for me:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("token", data.token);
```